# Css fade animation on element show

Tags: css, animation

i have this template http://t2themes.com/themes/workout/demo
and im trying to animate a div the way the site animates every element, article etc but i cant find the correct code.
If i use this code:

`div.anim {
    -webkit-animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    -moz-animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    -o-animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    opacity: 0; }`

my div animated but it animates on page load. i want to be animated when it will apeear on screen like the PROGRAMS section on the demo.
Also i want to do this on 6 divs and with my code they all animate the same time, i want the animation to be like in the demo, one at a time

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're using jQuery to load the elements when the user scrolls to that position on the screen. You'll need to implement some jQuery/JS to detect where the user is on the page and then show the element.

What they're doing is adding a class of 'animate' (an arbitrary class name) when the user reaches that position at which point they do their animation.

This snippet below detects when the user has scrolled and if the user has scrolled past 500px then it added a class (in this case called) 'animate' to the (in this case) ID.

Hope that helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 500 ) {
                $('#ELEMENTID').addClass('animate');
            }
        })
    });
})(jQuery);
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, is there any other way except the number of px? because with 500px it will not be the same for every post

Comment: Yes and no. You can measure the position of a relative element and use that variable as your marker. Make sense?

Comment: ok i have manage to do it with the help of this code http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/
now i want to make this code to be executed not simultaneously but to have a little delay for every div that will be animated. i want to be animated in an order from left to right with a delay of 500ms. how i can do that? every div has the same class

Comment: if i add different id in every div and add a different delay before the animation is a bad approach?

Comment: Somehow I missed this reply. How'd you make out?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand the question. i want to animate 3 elements in a row and i want them to be animated from left to right with a little delay

Comment: Edited the answer based on wanting to do them on a delay.

Comment: im using this code and it doesnt do anything, do you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/zsy5E/

Comment: your code works for a fixed position from scrolltop. i want to be more flexible like this example http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/ i have manage to animate them but they animate all at the same time

Comment: my current code: i want when #art-1 is shown #art1-3 to be animated with a 300ms delay each and when #art-4 is shown #art4-6 to be animated with a 300ms delay
check it here http://jsfiddle.net/56BDh/